# Android: Socket connection not working in a specific phone

Tags: android, sockets

```
 Socket connection = new Socket("192.168.1.200", 6000); // 6000 is the standard port for the device to which i am connecting
 InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Socket connection as implemented above does not work on LGP500(Android) but works fine on HTC Desire(Android). Could someone tell me what could be wrong...And the weird part is that it used to work fine in LG P500 before, stopped working all of a sudden...tried doing a factory reset..but it was no use still...

I get a SocketException: Network unreachable....

Would be really happy if someone could help me out on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That IP address is for a local subnet (probably WiFi) so make 100% sure the phone is using WiFi and not 3G for networking.

Comment: yes, in the phone AccessPoint is enabled and i am connecting to a wifi device of that IP...

Comment: Print out your IP address(es) and subnet, I bet you are not where you think you are on the network.

Comment: okie...then how is it that the same thing works on HTC Desire ?